# Django truncating am/pm in form time input

Tags: javascript, python, django, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form with a date/time input, with the input interface provided by Bootstrap 3 datetimepicker. When I attempt to submit the form, it gives me a validation error, as the time is invalid due to the am/pm component. How can I change the format that the model accepts as a valid date/time so that it correctly parses the am/pm component? Or is there a way to pre-process the date within JS?

views.py

```
    def new_appointment_existing_client(request):
        form = NewAppointmentExistingClientForm()

        context = {'form': form}
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = NewAppointmentExistingClientForm(data=request.POST)
            context['form'] = form
            #form.data['date'] =  datetime.datetime.strptime(form.data['date'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %p')

            if form.is_valid():

                form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/calendar/')
        return render(request, 'new_appointment.html', context)
```

new_appointment.html

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}

    {% block startscripts %}

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

    {% endblock startscripts %}


    {% block content %}

    <h3>Create an Appointment</h3>
    <br>
    <br>

    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-6'>
            <form method='POST' action ='/new_appointment/' id='id_new_appointment_form' enctype="multipart/form-data">

                {{ form.as_p }}
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% if form.errors %}
                <div class='form-group has-error'>
                    <span class='help-block'>{{ form.text.errors }}</span>
                </div>
                {% endif %}

                <input type="submit" id='id_form_submit' value="Submit" />

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    {% endblock content %}

    {% block endscripts %}
        <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>


    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                jQuery("#id_date").datetimepicker({
                    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a'
                });

        });

    </script>
    {% endblock endscripts %}
```

models.py

```
    class Appointment(models.Model):
        date = models.DateTimeField()
        appointment_person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

forms.py

```
    class NewAppointmentExistingClientForm(forms.models.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Appointment
            fields = ('date',
                'appointment_person',
                )
            widgets = {
            'date': forms.DateTimeInput(format=['%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p']),
```

}

Answer (score 0):

DateTimeField includes an [`input_formats`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#datetimefield) parameter that lets you specify the formats that are accepted; you can add one that includes am/pm:

```
date = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %p'])
```

Comment: Added the input format as a widget since I am using a `models.ModelForm` (I've edited the question to show the new widget). I read the docs and it looks like the option is switched to `format` when it is part of a widget. It looks like the string is correct, as when I check the value of `datetime.datetime.strptime(form.data['date'], '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p')`, I get the correct datetime object, but when I try to submit the form I am still getting a `['Enter a valid date/time.']` error. Any idea why that might be the case?

Comment: Because widgets are for display, not validation; that's why I gave you the example with a field. There's no need to change anything from the code I gave above.

Answer (score 0):

If you use this Date Time format everywhere, You should override two defaults settings in your **settings.py** file:

```
DATETIME_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p'
```

[DATETIME_FORMAT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#date-format) value will be the default format used te render date time fields in templates

For validation, i advice rewriting the default [DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#date-input-formats) tuple, which elements are used to validate date time fields by testing them in order.
Just add your desired format as the first element of this tuple, i mean DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS[0] .

Default is

```
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS (
    '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',     # '2006-10-25 14:30:59'
    '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f',  # '2006-10-25 14:30:59.000200'
    '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',        # '2006-10-25 14:30'
    '%Y-%m-%d',              # '2006-10-25'
    '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',     # '10/25/2006 14:30:59'
    '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f',  # '10/25/2006 14:30:59.000200'
    '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',        # '10/25/2006 14:30'
    '%m/%d/%Y',              # '10/25/2006'
    '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S',     # '10/25/06 14:30:59'
    '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f',  # '10/25/06 14:30:59.000200'
    '%m/%d/%y %H:%M',        # '10/25/06 14:30'
    '%m/%d/%y',              # '10/25/06'
)
```

Update it with your format  **'%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p'** at first :

```
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS (
    '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p',
    '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',     # '2006-10-25 14:30:59'
    '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f',  # '2006-10-25 14:30:59.000200'
    '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',        # '2006-10-25 14:30'
    '%Y-%m-%d',              # '2006-10-25'
    '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',     # '10/25/2006 14:30:59'
    '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f',  # '10/25/2006 14:30:59.000200'
    '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',        # '10/25/2006 14:30'
    '%m/%d/%Y',              # '10/25/2006'
    '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S',     # '10/25/06 14:30:59'
    '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f',  # '10/25/06 14:30:59.000200'
    '%m/%d/%y %H:%M',        # '10/25/06 14:30'
    '%m/%d/%y',              # '10/25/06'
)
```

Now default rendering and validation should work as expected without adding any parameter to date time fields.

keep your date time field clean :

```
date = models.DateTimeField()
```